# External Hard Drive with HFS+ file system mounted read only in OSMC

Tags: filesystem, permissions

I used this hard drive with Raspbmc with no problems, but since I updated to OSMC, this seems to mount the disk as read only. I need to change some permissions and modes and I get this message:

```
chmod 775 Completed/
chmod: changing permissions of ‘Completed/’: Read-only file system
```

The drive is in /media and it is automatically mounted by OSMC, I didn't do it manually.

My `fstab` looks like this:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot    vfat     defaults,noatime    0   0
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /        ext4     defaults,noatime    0   0
```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/fstab`?

Comment: Is journaling disabled on the HFS+ volume?  Linux appears to not natively support read-write to journaled HFS+ volumes, see http://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write

Comment: Thanks, @HeatfanJohn. I solved my problem with your link. What should I do now with my question? Should it be closed as duplicate and linked to that question?